# Geometry nodes - Rotation to Direction

Tags: geometry-nodes

Why method on picture nor working as intended? It provides some random direction (I want Z direction of object). I just want to copy rotation from object to generated mesh/curve line

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although they are both ordered collections of 3 numbers, Directions and Rotations are different things.

- A **Direction** is a **vector** in a 3D space, composed of **lengths** in the X direction,Y direction, and Z direction of that space.
- An Euler **Rotation** is a **transformation**: a series of **angles** through which some collection of vectors is rotated about the X,Y, and Z axes of the given space.
- In a GN tree, the overall 'space' is that of the modified object; measured along the object's own X,Y and Z axes.

You have plugged a Rotation into a Direction.

The simplest way to line your laser beam up with the your handle would be to make the GN-created beam a modification *of* the handle, with the handle as the input Geometry. Then, from your illustration, the curve's direction would always be (0,0,-1).

However, if you want the beam to be a modification of another (perhaps dummy) object, then you have to compensate for the difference in orientations between the modified object and the handle.

You want the **Direction** of the beam to be whatever (0,0,-1) becomes when it has been rotated though the same angles as the handle, so this is one way to get hold of that:

[image]

Comment: I've glossed over what X,Y and Z _are_ in Euler rotations.. how the rotation about one axis changes the meaning of the rotation about the next, and why the order of rotations matters. [This](https://youtu.be/zc8b2Jo7mno?t=8) is a nice explanation.

Comment: Thank you for your attention!
So there is 3 types of vector data: Coordinate, Euler Rotations and Directions?

Comment: @AlexanderBicukow   Strictly, I suppose... 'Coordinates' are just a way of referring to a set of numbers defining a measurement in some space.. (that could be 2D, 3D, Polar, Spherical) ... A 'Vector' is a line with a length and a direction. The difference between one end and the other of a vector is given by a set of coordinates. 'Direction' is the direction of a vector, ignoring its length. Specifically, the vector's length is ignored by setting it to 1: 'Normalizing' it. A 'Point' is where one end of a vector is, when the other end is at (0,0,0).

Comment: @AlexanderBicukow  An 'Euler Rotation' is not a vector. But it is an ordered set of 3 numbers, so it can be handled by nodes which expect vectors.